# Optimize the time complexity of program which computes the number of different pairs of numbers like described below

Tags: java, optimization, time-complexity

As I am pretty new to java, I'm struggeling with optimization of the time complexity of my programs. I have written a simple code which takes an array, and counts how many pairs of numbers there are for which the element with the lower index in the array is greater than the element with the greater index.

For example, if you have the array: [9,8,12,14,10,54,41], there will be 4 such pairs: (9,8),(12,10),(14,10) and (54,41).

I tried to optimize the code by not just comparing every element with every other one. I aimed for a time complexity of `n log n`. I have not yet figured out a way to write this code in a more efficient manner. I hope my question is clear.

The code(I have omitted adding the heapsort code, as it's not related to my question.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    class Main4 {
    static int n;
    static int[] A;

    // "A" is the input vector.
    // The number of elements of A can be accessed using A.length
            static int solve(int[] A) {
        int counter = 0;
        int[] B = new int[n];
        B = A.clone();
        heapSort(B);

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
                while( B[j] == Integer.MIN_VALUE&&j+1<n) {
                    j=j+1;
                }
                if (A[i] != B[j]) {
                    counter++;
                } else {
                    B[j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;         }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ntestcases = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int testno = 0; testno < ntestcases; testno++) {
            n = scanner.nextInt();
            A = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                A[i] = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println(solve(A));
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "how many possible pairs are there" or "What's the biggest number of pairs you can create"?

Comment: for example if you have the array: [9,8,12,14,10,54,41] there will be 4 such pairs: (9,8),(12,10),(14,10) and (54,41).

Comment: This really has nothing to do with java - it's just an algorithm

Comment: @Arkadiy I am just unsure how to optimize the problem using java as an instrument...

Comment: @Arkadiy what would be a better platform for this kind of questions?

Comment: This is not a matter of platform. You can write this algorithm in any general purpose imperative language. The question is, does the algorithm you need exist?

Comment: @Arkadiy you are right, maybe that would be the better question to ask myself... Probably not if I'm trying to also sort the array, right?

Comment: Consider the input array of pre-sorted numbers: { n, n-1, ..., 4,3,2,1}. Here, every element pairs with every element that follows it. This results in O(n^2) pairs. I have hard time thinking how you can count them in less than O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all possible pairs.

You can check from left to right to find all the matches. That's `O(n^2)` solution. As suggested by Arkadiy in the comments, this solution is okay for the worst case of the input.

I came up with the idea that you might want to store elements in sorted order AND keep the original unsorted array.

You keep the original array and build binary search tree. You can find the element with original index `i` in time `O(lgn)` and remove it in `O(lgn)`, which is great. You can also determine the number of values smaller than ith element with tiny additional cost.

To be able to count the elements smaller than, each node has to store the number of its children + 1. When you remove, you simply decrement the number of children in each node on your way down. When you insert, you increment the number of children in each node on your way down. When you search for a node you store the value root node has in variable and

- do nothing when you go to the right child,
- subtract the number child has from your variable when you go to the left child

Once you stop (you found the node), you subtract the value right child has (0 if there is no right child) and decrement the value.

You iterate over the original array from left to right. At each step you find element in your tree and calculate how many elements that are smaller are in tree. You know how many smaller than your current are there and you also know that all elements in the tree have greater index than the current element, which know how many elements you can pair it up with! You remove this element from the tree after you calculate the number of pairs. You do that n times. Lookup and removing from the tree is `O(lgn)` == `O(nlgn)` time complexity! The total time is `O(nlgn + nlgn) = O(nlgn)`!!

Chapter 12 of *Introduction to algorithms* (3rd edition) explains in depth how to implement BST. You may also find many resources on the Internet that explain it with pictures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! But yes, there are some things I still don't quite get. How do you sort an array in O(n) time? I couldn't find any approach that needs less than nlogn. Also I do not really understand the last part of your answer (starting from "You can remove that element..." until "...you can pair it up to". I'm sure there's no problem with your way of expressing it, but with my lack of understanding, I'm sorry and thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @chala I changed the algorithm almost completely, it had flaws. I still have to come up with one thing, but the algorithm should be okay now.

Comment: yes this seems much better, thanks! I understand the way you describe it. My problem is, I don't know how I'd implement those things in java. (for example a binary search tree..)

Answer (score 0):

#### Divide and conquer 1 (merge-sort like)

Split the whole list `W` into two parts `L` and `R` of early equal lengths. The count for `W` is the sum of

- counts for `L` and `R`
- the number of pairs `(l, r)` with `l > r` where `l` and `r` belong to `L` and `R` respectively.

The first bullet is recursion. The second bullet does not depend of the ordering of the lists `L` and `R`. So you can sort them and determine the result using a single pass through both lists (count all smaller `r` in sorted `R` for the first element of sorted `L`, the count for the second can now be computed incrementally, etc).

The time complexity is given by

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) + O(n log n)
```

which I guess is `O(n log n)`. Anyway, it's much smaller than `O(n*n)`.

You could improve it a bit by using merge sort: You need sorted `L` and this can be obtained by merging sorted `LL` and sorted `LR` (which are the two parts of `L` in the recursive step).

#### Divide and conquer 2 (quick-sort like)

Select an element `m` such that the number of bigger and smaller elements is about the same (the median would be perfect, but a randomly chosen element is usable, too).

Do a single pass through the array and count how many elements smaller than `m` are there. Do a second pass and count the pairs `(x, y)` with `x` placed to the left of `y` and `x >= m` and `m > y`.

Split the list into two parts: elements `e >= m` and the remaining ones. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: So for the second idea, how would you count the pairs (x,y) in less than $n^2$ ?

Comment: @chala Incrementally. Note that I don't compare `x` with `y`, both gets only compared with `m`. Keep the track of `y < m` to the right of the current position. Start at the first position (`O(n)`) initialization. When the current number is `>= m`, add the count to the total. Move to the next position is `O(1)`.